# Shorter Comparison in JS and other Languages

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I was wondering if i could write this

```
if ( (a > b) == (a > c) ) { ...
```

instead of this

```
if ( (a > b) && (a > c) ) || ( (a < b) && (a < c) ) { ...
```

a, b and c are numbers

Comment: You are comparing boolean values so yes it would work, you just have to be careful that it means the same. But, why don't you try by yourself? Experiment is the best way to learn imo :)

Comment: @Flo i tried it, it worked, i was just wondering if there were special cases, where these 2 expressions were not the same

Comment: @MohamedBenkedadra - Those two particular expressions are not the same in a **non**-special case (`a`, `b`, and `c` are all the same value); see Scott Hunter's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. In JavaScript, the comparison operators result in booleans, which can be directly compared with `==`/`===` and `!=`/`!==`, there's no conversion involved in those comparisons. (They can also be compared with `>` and `<` and such: `true` is greater than `false`. In that case, there is conversion involved, they get converted to numbers, `true` => `1` && `false` => `0`.)

Your first code block will branch into the `if` block if `a > b` and `a > c`, or if `a <= b` and `a <= c`. (That's not quite what your second block does, mind, as [Scott Hunter points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56672440/157247).) The correct comparison would be that this:

```
if ( (a > b) == (a > c) ) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( (a > b) && (a > c) ) || (a <= b) && (a <= c) ) {
```

Let's check:

```js
function check(a, b, c) {
    // Your first code block
    const r1 = (a > b) == (a > c);
    // Your second, which isn't _quite_ the same
    const r2 = ( (a > b) && (a > c) ) || ( (a < b) && (a < c) );
    // My second
    const r3 = ( (a > b) && (a > c) ) || ( (a <= b) && (a <= c) );
    console.log(a, b, c, "=>", r1, r2, r3);
}
check(1, 2, 3);
check(2, 1, 3);
check(3, 2, 1);
check(1, 1, 2);
check(2, 2, 1);
check(2, 1, 2);
check(1, 1, 1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
 }
```

Comment: I would have thought OP was interested in finding a shorter version of the second expression, but accepting this answer would seem to argue against that.

Answer (score 4):

You can write it, but they are not equivalent expressions (try having all 3 variables be the same number).